# $SU(n)$ generators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, matrix-decomposition

What is the generalization of the Pauli matrices and Dirac matrices in higher dimensions? I am actually looking for $\sqrt{\mathbb{I}}$ but I can't use the principal root which is just $\mathbb{I}$. For $n=3$, I found that the Gell-Mann matrices don't work. I'm thinking that these actually are the $SU(n)$ generators. Any ideas?